# noting is working in catch block in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, exception, try-catch

i have a simple express server in which i have function, in this function i try to access data from mongoDB , here is the code

```
const  test =async()=>{
try{
    const data = await User.findOne({_id: "1234"})
}catch(err){
    const data = await User.findOne({_id: "4567"})
}
```

in this function, try block is working fine but whenever error occurs code inside catch block is not working, i have try return and console.log() in catch block which is also not working, here is code

```
catch(err){
   console.log("hello")
}
```

or

```
catch(err){
   return "hello"
}
```

nothing is not working in catch block, i cant understand this problem please help me

**Edit**

the above code is simple example of my problem the actual code is following

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  data.time = new Date();
  data._id = uniqid();
  data.orderStatus = "Pending";
  const tradeData = await TradePara.create(data);
  try {
     algoTrade(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

i am facing issue with the algoTrade function, inside this function i am calling some apis with axios

Comment: Please update the question when you add more information - the code in a comment that answer does not provide a solution is in the wrong place :-)

Comment: A possible explanation dould be that `user.findOne` doesn't reject the promise it returns after an error occurs, leaving the returned promise permanently pending.

Comment: yes problem is with unresolved promise i have read this article https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a and try methods motioned in the article but still im facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue with your code in comments. The issue is that catch block is not implemented to catch error thrown by try block hence the code terminates use it like this

```html
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    data.time = new Date();
    data._id = uniqid();
    data.orderStatus = "Pending";
    const tradeData = await TradePara.create(data);
    try {
        algoTrade(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("not working", e);
    }
});
```

instead of using catch{}, implement catch block.

Comment: i have try this, its not working, its print error on terminal but its not print console,log statement

Comment: my goal is not print error on terminal , the main goal is put some data in database when error occurs, which is not working in catch block

Comment: Just put the function to store data in database in catch block. Whenever the error will be thrown that function will run.

Comment: i have try this but its not working, i searched on web and i found the problem that is my function is asynchronous in nature that's why catch block never works. i read this article https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a and try these methods but stills i cant resolve the issue